# Do I need to compile my code on the ubuntu server?

Tags: mern, ubuntu-20.04, npm-build

When I run 'npm run build' in the vsCode terminal ,within a few seconds, it compiles. However, when I run 'npm run build' on the ubuntu 20.04 server after I've pulled my code from gihub, it takes hours and then never actually compiles. The reason is usually a memory leak, but I started increasing the memory allocation, and now the server disconnects before it ever finishes the build.

My app is a mern app, does anyone know if this is an issue with my code or is the issue that I don't need to build my app on the ubuntu server? For example could I build the app it vscode first, as that seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to build the app in ubuntu server in order to deploy the same. You can build your app anywhere and copy the content of the build folder to the server for deploying.

Comment: Ok, thank you, where's the dist folder though?

Comment: sorry, my bad, it is the build folder, not dist.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. Will I be able to pull this folder from github or will I have to manually copy the folder onto the ubuntu server?

Comment: usually, the build folder will be excluded from pushing to git using .gitignore, you will have to build locally and then copy it over.

Comment: How do I copy the folder over to a unbuntu 20.04 server?

Comment: you can use scp or ftp to copy your files or folders to Linux server, that's up to how you have enabled access to the server